# Error al generar APK: "All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification"

Tags: java, android

Cuando intento generar el APK en Android studio me sale este mensaje de error:

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
> java.util.zip.ZipException: 
> duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/appindexing/Action$Builder$StatusType.class
> ```

Estoy usando google maps, al parecer es un error de duplicidad pero no sabría como mapearlo.

No sé, si tendrá algo que ver pero en mi archivo gradle me sale un error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled  true
    applicationId "com.example.bryan.pruebawebservice"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
//ACA ESTA EL ERROR ---->>>
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

EL error es:

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 9.8.0, 10.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

> All com.google.android.gms **libraries must use the exact same version**
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 9.8.0, 10.0.1. Examples include
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1

Usa la misma versión de `com.google.android.gms:play-services` en este caso la 10.0.1 de acuerdo a tu `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Tal vez se requiera de instalar el repositorio de esta versión, al terminar simplemente sincroniza el `build.gradle` con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro:

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same    version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 9.8.0, 10.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1

Mira lo que estás compilando:

```
...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
...

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
...
```

El compilador se enfada y te dice: *cuando se trate de com.google.android.gms ... no me digas que use dos versiones, o la 9.8.0 o la 10.0.1* :)

**Entonces:**

De la librería **com.google.android.gms** que tienes en el gradle que se muestra erróneo:

Pon la versión más reciente. O sea, cambia:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
```

por

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Si sigue dando error, deja solamente :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```